# mimic `reduceWhile` like operator

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a flux of values that I need to 'merge' until they met a certain condition. 
I don't want to use outer variable as buffer to check my condition is met but I cannot find a way to do a 'reduceWhile' or 'bufferWhile' operation  because I don't have access to buffer (with `.buffer`) to check that I have enough data to pass the result downstream.

I have:

```
                ohlcIntfFlux
                        .reduce(OHLCIntf::mergeWith)
                        .filter(timeFrameProvider::isBarComplete)
                        .map(this::makeBar)
                        .subscribe(pub::next)
```

but this reduces whole stream and then checks filter.

I need to reduce until the condition in filter is met then pass it downstream.

Hope it's clear enough...

Thank you!

Comment: can you clarify your requirements? you cannot use something like `buffer(maxSize).map(buffer -> mergedValuesIn(buffer))` ?

Comment: I can not do that because I don't know what the buffer size should be. basically I need to do `mergeWith` until `isBarComplete` is filled.

Comment: if `isBarComplete` is a boolean-returning method, there's `bufferUntil(Predicate)`

Comment: but how do you access that buffer in the predicate?

Comment: my bad the method name and class made it look like it was an external flag unrelated to the buffer

Comment: anyway... something like `bufferWhile(..)` with access to that buffer in predicate is what I need. if any additional thoughts ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this how I done it:

```
ConnectableFlux.create(pub ->
                ohlcIntfFlux
                        .scan((i, acc) -> {
                            if (!timeFrameProvider.isBarComplete(acc))
                                return acc.mergeWith(i);

                            pub.next(makeBar(acc));
                            return i;
                        })
                        .subscribe()
        )
```

it does what I want to, but if you can suggest more functional way, I would be glad to hear that